# Show Woocommerce search query results within multiple custom fields at a time

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for my car inventory website and I have successfully updated the default woocommerce search and now it works with my custom fields.

Here is the code:

```
function dvs_search_form( $query ) {
    $key_fields = array ( 'dvs_fuel','dvs_transmission' );
    $value_field = $query->query_vars['s'];
    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';
    if ( $value_field != '' ) {
        $filter_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
        foreach ( $key_fields as $one_field ) {
            array_push ( $filter_query , array (
                'key' => $one_field,
                'value' => $value_field,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ) );
        }
        $query->set( 'meta_query' , $filter_query );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'dvs_search_form');
```

But this search form only works with one custom field at a time.

Like I want if a product has these custom fields:
`dvs_fuel = petrol`
`dvs_transmission = automatic`

and a customer wants to search vehicles with `petrol` and `automatic` and add these two terms in search input, it displays the search result with products that have `petrol` and `automatic` in custom fields.

Comment: You should better have dropdowns (or checkboxes) like in your other question, with custom query strings… Actually you are using the "s" query string. Instead you should have dvs_fuel and dvs_transmission as query strings…

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, but the client told me to add multiple custom fields term in a search query. 
Sir, you have helped me in the previous question and I shall be very thankful to you if you assist me in this question with your expertise :)
Regards

Comment: For each **meta key**, you need to have a query string, so your search url will be: a bit like:
`www.domain.com/?s&dvs_fuel=petrol&dvs_transmission=automatic`.Then you will be able to get in your code the value for each with: `$query->query_vars['dvs_fuel']` and  `$query->query_vars['dvs_transmission']`… Do you get it?

Comment: I am sorry sir, I still didn't understand :( I am still in a woocommerce learning phase and after working on 3 hours I developed how to enable woocommerce default search works with custom fields, but now its been 4 more hours gone and I am unable to solve the issue :( I am sorry

Comment: With your provided code we don't see or understand how your search works... So try to provide also the related code that displays your search filters (and makes the search)…

Comment: Ok Sir, I am still trying, but once again I want to explain to you. This is a demo website link: https://earnonlinepk.com and search are working with custom fields, Like If I enter HYBRID in search it gives result or I enter AUTOMATIC in search it provides results. 

1. https://i.imgur.com/DsPLqVj.png
2. https://i.imgur.com/OD4aLph.png

But the search is not working If I enter both HYBRID and AUTOMATIC, I want it should provide the search results with products product that has both HYBRID and AUTOMATIC in their custom fields.

3. https://i.imgur.com/rwq7os5.png

Regards.